# How to show a notice for required plugins while installing new theme in our wordpress project

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a theme for distribution purpose in wordpress and I am new in wordpress. I used some plugins in my theme. I want to show a notice for required plugins which is neccesary for my theme who would use my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [TGM Plugin Activation library](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) to  show a notice for required plugins